# Is it possible to choose what to display in Artifactory’s repository browser?

Tags: directory, artifactory

Is it possible to choose what to display in Artifactory’s repository browser? By default, it shows all virtual, remote, local repos but this doesn’t look too organized when you have lots of products and teams using the same Artifactory. For example, can we just show virtual repos and hide local repos?

Also, a cache folder is automatically displayed for each remote repository (e.g. jcenter-cache). Can we hide those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to filter your tree browser view in Artifactory. This, however, will change soon as in the next month or so in the new release of JFrog Artifactory you will be able to choose what to show in your tree browser. Please note that the filtering configurations will be per browser, meaning that if there are 50 developers that are using the same Artifactory instance, each will have his own filter. There is no "One filter for all" option.

Regarding the '-cache' of the remote repositories, this is being created automatically upon caching artifact via remote repositories and allow you to see what artifacts were cached in the remote cache. You can't disable the view of those repositories.

You can see a preview of the filter feature in the "What's new in JFrog Artifactory" Webinar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o1uVWSqZnk